# Remove warscore limit

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

It seems like in EU4, the warscore requirements are too strict. For instance, when fighting a large country such as Spain or France, it is impossible to take over all their territory in one war, even if you completely destroy all their armies and occupy all their territory.

This strikes me as unrealistic, and more importantly, hinders my enjoyment of the game. I understand that the mechanic was balanced for multiplayer, which makes sense, since I play only singleplayer. I would like to somehow adjust warscore costs so that any country, no matter how large, can be annexed in its entirety when 100%  warscore is attained.

Are there any mods that allow you to do this? Can I do it myself?

Answer (score 6):

I'd rather see it as unrealistic to just conquer one large nation in one fell swoop.
If you could, you'd be swamped in rebellions as the people really don't like having their cultural identity taken away. How are you going to control this many newly added provinces to your realm? Empires created like this historically collapsed within a few decades (see Alexander, the mongols or Napoleon).
Your neighbors would be very concerned and feel threatened, especially when you conquer territory without even a flimsy claim to it.

In game terms, simply changing the warscore limit won't help you much. Imagine you take the entirety of france in one war.
Overextension would kill you. Annexing a country like this in one go would result in easily 1000% overextension, meaning your realm would grind to a complete halt and massive rebellions within a year.
Aggressive expansion would kill you. The AE acquired through such an annexation would immediately create a massive coalition, which then quickly destroys you.

The only mod coming to my mind is Arcade Mode, which accelrates the entire game (tech, sieges, everything immensely; disables truce timers as well overextension and AE.)

Comment: I have no problem with the risk of rebellion, overextension, aggressive expansion and so on. My only concern is the warscore limit.

Comment: You have no problem with circumstances, which will cause you to be overrun extremly quickly? Let me give you an example of what 1000% overextension alone will do: Trigger a nasty event every month (rebels, loss of stability and so on), +50 national unrest, +500% stability cost and merc cost, -20 diplomatic reputation. You WILL have rebellions all over your country very quickly, too many for any army to possibily handle. Your manpower will be quickly depleted, mercs are impossible to afford and your realm will break apart. No matter how strong you think you are, this WILL happen.

Comment: Yes, I have no problem with it. If I get rebellions, so be it. The question is about removing warscore limit.

Comment: I have to agree with Dulkan. Being able to annex an entire large country in one go would completely ruin the game and the checks and balances in the game engine that punish too fast expansion are a large part of the fun for me. I think you are being unneccessarily dismissive to someone who has given you some very sound answers.

Comment: Use console commands and cheats. You're practically asking this

Answer (score 0):

You could just create a new CB and make annexing any province cost less.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the *defines.lua* file in EU4's common section, and search for *PEACE_COST_DEMAND_PROVINCE*, you should come across the line *PEACE_COST_DEMAND_PROVINCE = 1*. You can change the value to be smaller, even to absurd values like 0.01. It won't allow you to annex any country with 100% warscore, but it lowers the warscore cost of the individual provinces.